# Get first name, last name, phone number from user profile?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-account

I'm trying to get user's info (first name, last name, phone, email, .etc) from profile. Below is my code, the weird thing is that there're several records (`cursor.moveToNext()` works several times), one of them contains email in the phone value, the other contains address in email field. All I need is one correct record, instead of picking and combining pieces.

I do add required permissions, so there shouldn't be problems there.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

Any tip? thanks

Below is my code

```
private static final String[] PERSONAL_ADDRESS_PROJ = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,

    };

    private static final int INDEX_GIVEN_NAME = 0;
    private static final int INDEX_FAMILY_NAME = INDEX_GIVEN_NAME + 1;
    private static final int INDEX_PHONE_NUMBER = INDEX_FAMILY_NAME + 1;
    private static final int INDEX_EMAIL = INDEX_PHONE_NUMBER + 1;

private SignupModel searchForProfile() {


        final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?" + " OR " +
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?" + " OR " +
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?" ;

        String [] args =  new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, PERSONAL_ADDRESS_PROJ, selection, args, null);
        SignupModel model;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            try {
                do
                {
                    final String givenName = cursor.getString(INDEX_GIVEN_NAME);
                    final String familyName = cursor.getString(INDEX_FAMILY_NAME);
                    final String phone = cursor.getString(INDEX_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    final String email = cursor.getString(INDEX_EMAIL);

                    model = new SignupModel(email,null,null,givenName, familyName, phone,null);

                }while (cursor.moveToNext()); //loop for debugging purpose

            } catch (Exception e) {
                model = null;
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }

        } else {
            LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Couldn't find profile entry");
            model = null;
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get all the information in a single record as all are stored as separate line items according to the MIMETYPE. When you read the cursor you should first read the MIMETYPE from the cursor and then read the data from the corresponding column.

To explain as you have given three mimetypes in your selection you will get at least three records if the user has entered all the information, for name you will get one record which will have DISPLAY_NAME, GIVEN_NAME, FAMILY_NAME, etc.
You will also get one or more record for PHONE considering how many numbers he has added, each record will also contain the type (MOBILE,HOME, etc)
Same goes for EMAIL.

For name columns refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html)
Phone and Email are stored in DATA1 column.

[Phone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html)

[Email](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html)